# Java swing grid of buttons with different resize rules per column

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java-11

i'm trying to make a UI panel that serves like a form (Im not using GUI designer). Left side contains labels, and the right side contains text field, etc. I want to make it, so that when resized, only the right size (the text fields, change shape).

Currently, i am using `GridLayout(x, 2)` with one `JLabel` and `JTextField` per row.

So on resize, i wanna make it so that this goes
from `[(JLabel)|(JTextField)]`
to `[(JLabel)|(    JTextField    )]`
not `[(  JLabel  )|(  JTextField  )]`.

Plus, of course, i need to make sure that all of the rows always match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a single layout manager you could use a `GridBagLayout`.

For the components in the second column you would set the `weightx` constraint to 1.0f. This means any extra space will only be allocated to this component.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The topic on `Specifying Constraints` will explain in more detail how this constraint works.

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout can not be used for this. Use GridBagLayout or a easier to use layout manager, like MigLayout.

Comment: Could you propose how to set something like that? Because i think i missed such setting on it.